# Tool for migrating oracle table to CSV file

Tags: database, csv, oracle-database

I want to migrate data from oracle table to a csv file. Is there any tool for this migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you could use the "external tables" feature with `INSERT INTO external_table SELECT * FROM normal_table`. External tables are stored in CSV format on disk. If that sounds too complicated, take a look at [SQLcl](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2015/15-sep/o55sql-dev-2692807.html), which is a replacement to SQL*Plus written in Java. You could then spool output to a file and run a query like `SELECT /*csv*/ * FROM table`, and your "migration" would be done.

[image: screenshot]
<sup>*SQLcl* screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Apart from CSV, *SQLcl* can also directly output as HTML, JSON, INSERT statements, and much more, plus offers a bunch of additional features. The linked article will give you a brief overview (and download link). If you're more the visual type, there's also an [introductional video at YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HApdy-o525A).